# Remainder of $8\times 8\times 8\times 8\times 8\times 8$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

What is the remainder of $8\times 8\times 8\times 8\times  8\times  8$  divided by $7$ ?
It is related to modulo calculus.

Can somebody give me the hints to solve it ?

Comment: What's the remainder of $8$ when divided by $7$? What about $8\cdot 8$? Can you even find the remainder of $8\cdot 8 \cdot 8$? How do you think this continues?

Answer (score 6):

Hint: write all $8$'s as $7+1$.

Comment: And don't forget to insert parentheses...

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Otherwise, you might wind up with the remainder of $7+1\times7+1\times7+1\times7+1\times7+1\times7+1 = 7+7+7+7+7+7+1$? :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is like a clock that has instead of $12$ hours only $7$. The remainder $1$ shuffles then to the next hour. So try it with $13*13*13*13*13*13$ divided by $12$. You will get the insight.

Answer (score 0):

Divide each $8$  by $7$ and find reminder in each case  . Then multiply all . That's the answer .

As $ 8 $ mod $7$ is $1 $

$ 8\times 8\times 8\times 8\times 8\times 8 $ $\pmod  7 $  is $   1\times 1\times 1\times 1\times 1\times 1 $  which is $1 $

Beauty of this method :
This is very useful in case of large numbers .

Concept : 
You just factorise the number and then find remainder in each case . multiply all remainders  . if the result is greater than divisor then repeat it until  the remainder is less than divisor . once it is less than divisor that's the answer .

Comment: Yes, but it'd be nice if you indicated why this works, as [TZakrevskiy's older answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/417244) does.